# Android set unix timestamp to a DatePicker

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I'm trying to set a unix timestamp to an Android DatePicker using this code :

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(((long)unixTimeStamp*1000));
datePickerDateDue.init(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), null);
```

But the Android DatePicker is set to a wrong value (1 Jan 1900)

(((i don't like playing with dates...)))

Comment: Can you show the `unixTimeStamp()` method, please? Also, what is the "wrong value"?

Comment: wrong value is 1 Jan 1900, and for the unix time stamp it could be something like 1343336160 for today: Thu, 26 Jul 2012 20:56:00 GMT

Comment: It "could be"? Have you logged it to ensure the value is correct? Additionally, you should be using `Calendar` for this since many `Date` methods are deprecated.

Comment: yes i did Eric even hard coded with a value directly and still wrong, none of the methods that i use are deprecated but i don't mind using Calendar instead if you think that could solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per comments, try using the `Calendar` class. You can also `Log` the outputs of `year`, `month`, and `day` to ensure they are correct.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(((long) unixTimeStamp) * 1000L);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
datePickerDateDue.init(year, month, day, null);
```

Comment: ok i edited your anwswer and it's working like this but the Long.parseLong() is not really pretty, so if you have any other way you can edit your answer again ;) Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried using `((long) unixTimeStamp) * 1000L`? If you can do it mathematically, that would be optimal.

Comment: i will remember to use Calendar in the future then instead of Date